# d3 zoom behavior in React Native

Tags: d3.js, react-native

In React Native I draw my charts with d3 and ART libraries.

```
export default class DevTest extends React.Component {

    static defaultProps = {
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
    }

    mainScaleX = d3Scale.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3Array.extent(chartDataTo, data => data.date))
        .range([0, this.props.width])

    mainScaleY = d3Scale.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3Array.extent(chartDataTo, data => data.value))
        .range([this.props.height, 0])

    rawChartValue = d3Shape.line()
        .x(data => this.mainScaleX(data.date))
        .y(data => this.mainScaleY(data.value))

    render(){

        return (
            <View>
                <Surface width = {this.props.width} height = {this.props.height}>
                    <Group x = {0} y = {0}>
                        <Shape
                            d = {this.rawChartValue(chartData)}
                            stroke = "#000"
                            strokeWidth = {1}
                        />
                    </Group>
                </Surface>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Is there any way to implement d3 svg-like zoom behavior, but without DOM mutation. For example, using some d3 pure functions with just x and y values as input to rescale mainScaleX and mainScaleY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PanResponder` from `react-native` and `zoomIdentity` from `d3-zoom` for that purpose.

Code example looks sometihng like this

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (event, { dx, dy }) => {
            const zoomIdentity = d3Zoom.zoomIdentity.translate(dx, dy)
            this._onDrag(zoomIdentity)
        },
    });
}

_onDrag(zoomIdentity){
    this.setState({
        rescaledX: zoomIdentity.rescaleX(this.state.mainScaleX),
        rescaledY: zoomIdentity.rescaleY(this.state.mainScaleY)
    })
}
```

And you pass your rescaled{X, Y} to a chart component

```
render(){
    return (
        <View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <Component 
                {...this.props}
                scaleX = {this.state.rescaledX}
                scaleY = {this.state.rescaledY}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```